# Rails Postgres Database – no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've just opened up a Rails project that I haven't accessed for about six months.

Hitting my .dev domain or running `rails c` gets me the following error:

> /Users/me/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize': fe_sendauth: **no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)**

Looking at my database config, I can see that there is indeed no password supplied, but looking back through my Git history I can see there never has been a password supplied in development.

Testing other rails projects, I get the same error, so I am now unable to run any rails projects locally.

I haven't (deliberately) touched Postgres at all since the last time I successfully ran a project locally.

Here is an example of a rails app that was working 10 days ago and now fails with the above error:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['APP_NAME'] %>_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['APP_NAME'] %>_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['APP_NAME'] %>_production

staging:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['APP_NAME'] %>_staging
```

[Update] This effects sites that never had an explicit user or password defined in their `database.yml` in the first place.

**What might have changed in my setup?**

Comment: Huh... gems' versions maybe? Are you accessing Postgres via Unix domain socket or over TCP/IP?

Comment: I haven't updated any gems since the last time everything worked. ANd I'm not accessing Postgres in any non-standad way.

Comment: That doesn't clear anything, they're both quite common, but different. Also, a sample of your `database.yml` might help.

Comment: Uhm... that does seem like domain socket access, in which case it should be logging in with the current Unix username and using passwordless "peer auth". The only possible reason I see is Postgres configuration changed. But you say you didn't touch it...

Comment: Maybe a postgresql package was updated and this changed postgresql configuration file? Check when the file was modified.